# How would I find a specific binary result in a binary source code?

Tags: c#, search, binary, indexof

I am trying to find binary code inside a given string of binary code. Where the search is for N code (variable based upon search parameters) and where the string of binary code is M (variable based upon search parameters).

For example I have determined I need to find 0110 in a binary string that is 20 bits long, 110001011011010101010.

Then I need to push the remaining code after our found code to another string value.

I am so very new I cannot start on this alone

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

Console.Write("Input your search text: ");
var text = Console.ReadLine();

System.IO.StreamReader file =
    new System.IO.StreamReader("SampleInput1.txt");

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains(text))
    {
        break;
    }

    counter++;
}

Console.WriteLine("Line number: {0}", counter);

file.Close();

Console.ReadLine();
```

I a not sure how to get the sampleinput1.txt to work nor other functions but this seems a likely avenue.

Comment: Use IndexOf("0110").  Then you can use SubString() methods to get the rest of the data.

Comment: So in your example you want to push `11010101010` and `10101010` to the other string value? (since it contains 0110 twice)

Comment: Thanks Jesse de Wit for noticing, thought I was careful not to do that, but the answer would be the first time it would show up.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the rest of the line by taking the index of the search text and then using that index to get a substring. See below for an example:

```
int lineNumber = 0;
string line;
Console.Write("Input your search text: ");
string text = Console.ReadLine();
string otherValue = null;
using (var reader = new StreamReader("SampleInput1.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        int index = line.IndexOf(text);
        if (index > -1)
        {
            otherValue = line.Substring(index);
            break;
        }

        lineNumber++;
    }
}

if (otherValue == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not found");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Line number: {0}", lineNumber);
    Console.WriteLine("Other value: '{0}'", otherValue);
}
```